# TPU training error: "No registered 'Cumsum' OpKernel for XLA_TPU_JIT devices compatible with node {{node RaggedConcat/Cumsum"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tpu

I am trying to train a model with a custom train step on TPU. The training works fine on GPU, but not on TPU. I believe I am not using a tensorflow operation that is not supported, according to this [ https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tensorflow-ops ] but the list for both the supported and unsupported functions are not exhaustive, and I am using functions not listed on either.

The error message mentions a ragged tensor, and there are only two lines of code where I have ragged tensors, which are in `train_step`

```
class CustomModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
        # on what you pass to `fit()`.
        x = data

        positveLabel = tf.constant( [1, 0], dtype=tf.int32 )
        negativeLabel = tf.constant( [0, 1], dtype=tf.int32 )

        pLabelBatch = tf.reshape(tf.tile( positveLabel, [tf.shape(x[0])[0]], name=None), [tf.shape(x[0])[0],2] )
        nLabelBatch = tf.reshape(tf.tile( negativeLabel, [tf.shape(x[0])[0]], name=None), [tf.shape(x[0])[0],2] )

        y = (pLabelBatch, pLabelBatch, nLabelBatch, nLabelBatch) 

        batch_label = tf.reshape(y, (tf.size(y)/2, 2), name=None)

        rs = tf.ragged.stack(x, axis=0)
        reg = rs.to_tensor()
        batch_input = tf.reshape(reg, (tf.shape(reg)[0]*tf.shape(reg)[1], tf.shape(reg)[2]))

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(batch_input, training=True)  # Forward pass
            # Compute the loss value
            # (the loss function is configured in `compile()`)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(batch_label, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)

        # Compute gradients
        _minimize(self.distribute_strategy, tape, self.optimizer, loss,
                self.trainable_variables)
        # Update weights
        # self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

specifically

```
        rs = tf.ragged.stack(x, axis=0)
        reg = rs.to_tensor()
```

I couldn't find anything online about ragged tensors being supported or unsupported.

I am trying to figure out how to fully interpret the error message.